# Javascript Radio Button Show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

Trying to get the text field `please specify` to show and hide. Here's my code.

`

Comment: what text field, there is no text field in HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is text field missing in code, so based on `Trying to get the text field please specify to show and hide`

HTML text-field

```
<label class="option" for="edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-fund-distribution-select-1">other (please specify)</label>
<input id="edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-widg-donation1otherdescription" type="text">
```

and JS code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-widg-donation1otherdescription").hide();
    $("#edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-fund-distribution-select-1").click(function () {
         if ($(this).val() === "0000~0000") {
             $("#edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-widg-donation1otherdescription").show();
         } else {
             $("#edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-widg-donation1otherdescription").hide();

         }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue7n59uw/)

In JS code you are binding the `label id="edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-fund-distribution-select"`

But to hide and show the text field if click on radio button like you said in question title, you have to bind the click function with radio button id `id="edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-fund-distribution-select-1"`

and this `$("#edit-submitted-distributions-fieldset-1-widg-donation1otherdescription").prop("disabled", false);` only makes the input not disable, it has nothing to do with hide / show the input.